# Open image with default image viewer in Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have in my Jquery-mobile/phonegap application an "img src" tag that put an image on my page. Is it possible to click on that image and the image will open with the default viewer in android? I tried a hyperlink with the uri but I get then a page with undefined.

uri:

```
    file:///mnt/sdcard/test/images.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you will need to make a plugin. That plugin should capture your data (/test/images.jpeg) and generate an Intent to open the file with the default Image viewer.

Check a blogpost of me. It is about an appstore Intent, but it should get you going.

http://teusink.blogspot.nl/2013/08/phonegap-android-appstore-plugin.html